# How do I get only the rows where the addition of a field in each row makes up a required quantity?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a quantity value which can be anything.  For this example lets assume it is 75.

I have a query which returns a set of rows showing the number of items in different bins scattered around the place (physically).  The list is in a sorted order.

I want to filter the rows to show only the rows that are needed to fulfil the required quantity.  These rows are in a sorted order and will always be required in a sorted order, i.e. only row 1 or rows 1 and 2, or 1,2,3 etc. but never rows 1,3,5 for example.

Here is an example that needs filtering to return only the first 2 rows for quantity = 75:

```
row  item count
1       20
2       60
3        7
4       20
```

If some sort of running total or quantity still required and a count of items remaining is possible that would be great too, but that might be a step too far.

Comment: Why are you doing this in SQL? You state `These rows are in a sorted order and will always be required in a sorted order`, but your example does not have the rows in order. Is this really the case?

Comment: @RyanGates - perhaps I should have called the row column sort order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server 2012 has direct support for cumulative sums.  In earlier versions, you need to do the calculation differently.  I like doing it with a correlated subquery:

```
select row, itemcount,
       (select sum(itemcount)
        from t t2
        where t2.row <= t.row
       ) as cumsum
from t
```

Next, you need the first row that is bigger than the given value.  For this, use a subquery and some arithmetic:

```
select t.row, t.itemcount
from (select row, itemcount,
             (select sum(itemcount)
              from t t2
              where t2.row <= t.row
             ) as cumsum
      from t
     ) t
where 75 > cumsum - itemcount and 75 <= cumsum;
```

The logic behind the `where` clause rather simple.  The `cumsum` has to be greater than `75` the cutoff value.  However, there can be multiple rows that meet this condition.  You want the want where the previous value of `cumsum` is less than `75` -- which you get by subtracting the current `itemcount`.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @target int = 75;

DECLARE @t TABLE (rownum int, value int);
INSERT @t VALUES (1,60),(2,20),(3,7),(4,20);

WITH t_sum AS (
  SELECT
    rownum,
    value,
    SUM(value) OVER(ORDER BY rownum) AS r_total
  FROM @t
)
SELECT
  rownum,value
FROM t_sum
WHERE r_total - value < @target
```